# Light Catcher Setup

Tags: lighting

I am familiar with the concept of the shadow catcher. I'd like to know -- are light catchers also possible? I have this scene where I am using light dispersion techniques to cast light onto a surface plane. I'd like to render this as a transparent PNG graphic and thus have the plane hidden -- and the light remain.

What would be an effective way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly... is there light added in the dispersion on the plane? Because usually I would say the white light is split up, so what you have there are colored shadows... areas, where only parts of the light spectrum are coming through.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I didnt give it a chance to render fully but you can see how light is hitting the surface of the plane behind the pyramid. I have a light source to the left and the idea is to have this refracted light hit the plane. Much like a shadow catcher renders the shadows falling on an object but hides the object itself, I want to render the light, but have the plane itself hidden. Is that possible?

Comment: What I mean is: isn't the refracted light hitting the plane simply the remaining light after being refracted, so only a fraction of the light which would hit the plane if there was no object. So it's not brightening the plane, it is just less shadow there. Which means it's still shadow, and you don't need a light catcher, but a shadow catcher. Or is the object focusing the light and it is brighter than it would be if there were no object? It's hard to tell from the screenshot and you don't show how the glass material is set up so that we could perhaps reproduce it to see for ourselves.